# get page title from previous page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one page on my site. This page have big functionality and there are many links from other pages to this page. And I want to know where from user coming to this page. I found `UrlReferrer` property in `Request` object, but it contain only `url`. But, I want page title.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it as query string parameter when generating the link.

Comment: This is good for several pages. Also, I have about 10 pages that contain one partial view (from this user go to big page) loaded via ajax. And, for this situation I don't know what exactly page title.

Answer (score 0):

You can store title in session for every request and then check it.

Comment: +1 with x2. You could store the page title in session with controller method of your page with big functionality. Then on your secondary page/s you can read the page title value from session. If page title is dynamic, will get set correctly each time method is executed. Not sure why you really want to do this but this should suffice...